# Unable to run jar file

Tags: java, jar

I was able to run GUI java programs runs on .jar extension file by building it.
But I was unable to run a simple program out of net beans by building it!
For Example
I couldnt run this program below by building it as jar file!

```
class A{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
  }
}
```

How can i run this type of program from .jar extension???

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd in from the folder that `jar` file is located and type this..

```
java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```

Any `jar` file can be executed using this way.

When you double click, program run and exit in a moment.. That's why you can't see..

Comment: can't i run it out of CMD???

Comment: Write `System.in.read();` at the end of your java code. It will work